# Drawing line without mxml (with ActionScript)

Tags: apache-flex, drawing, mxml, line

hai i want to draw a line with actionscript . Can anyone give me a hint
Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        private function drawLine():void 
        {
            var myShape:Shape =new Shape();
            myShape=new Shape() ;
            myShape.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x990000, .75);
            myShape.graphics.moveTo(10, 10);

            myShape.graphics.lineTo(25, 45);

        }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

<s:Button label="myButton" click="drawLine()"/>
```

`

Answer (score 6):

Notice that when you use the `myShape.graphics.moveTo` you are not drawing on the application itself because the `Graphic` object is for the `Shape` that you created.

Currently you have created the shape as a new object in memory and drawn a line on it.

```
 _____________           _____________
|             |         | __          |  
|             |         ||\ | <-shape |  
|             |         ||_\|         |  
|             |         |             |  
| Application |         | Memory      |  
|             |         |             |  
|_____________|         |_____________|
```

For it to show up in your application, you still need to use `addChild` to add the shape as a child of you Application or Component. [Adobe Reference Link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild())

```
 _____________           _____________
| __          |         |             |   
||\ | <-shape |         |             |   
||_\|         |         |             |  
|             |         |             |  
| Application |         | Memory      |  
|             |         |             |  
|_____________|         |_____________|
```

Try using `this.addChild` it should add your shape but remember that the coordinates that you drew on where for the Shape object not for you application.

```
private function drawLine():void 
{
    var myShape:Shape = new Shape();
    myShape = new Shape() ;
    myShape.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x990000, .75);
    myShape.graphics.moveTo(10, 10);

    myShape.graphics.lineTo(25, 45);
    this.addChild(myShape);
}
```

Comment: +1 for editing the original answer to format the code.  I guess you didn't have enough points to push it live; but I approved it for you.

Comment: I meant +1 for editing the original question, not the original answer.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use directly spark.primitives.Line to get any line with all sorts of styles and properties.

```
        private function drawLine():void
        {
            var newLn:Line = new Line();
            newLn.xFrom = 50;
            newLn.xTo = 200;
            newLn.y = 100;
            newLn.stroke = new SolidColorStroke(0xFF0000, 2);
            addElement(newLn);
        }
```

HTH,
FTQuest